# Convert NSArray to NSDictionary - Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

i'm trying to convert NSArray to NSDictionary using this code that i found in this post:
[Convert NSArray to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414852/convert-nsarray-to-nsdictionary?rq=1)

```
@implementation NSArray (indexKeyedDictionaryExtension)

- (NSDictionary *)indexKeyedDictionary
{
NSUInteger arrayCount = [self count];
id arrayObjects[arrayCount], objectKeys[arrayCount];

[self getObjects:arrayObjects range:NSMakeRange(0UL, arrayCount)];
for(NSUInteger index = 0UL; index < arrayCount; index++) { objectKeys[index] = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index]; }

return([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayObjects forKeys:objectKeys count:arrayCount]);
}

@end
```

However there is an error in the line of [self get objects:array objects,...],with message: Sending “NSString *_strong*to parameter of type _unsafe_unretained id* ”change retain/release properties of pointer. I assume this is because an ARC issue, since the post is in 2009.
Anyone know how to get rid the issue?thanks..

Comment: what is [self count] ?? self ?? display it in console by NSLog ? and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868603/sending-nsstring-strongto-parameter-of-type-unsafe-unretained-id-change-r

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YWYbStxK

Comment: What's the advantage of creating a dictionary where the key is just the index anyway?  None that I can see.

Comment: i try the pastebin link, and still error in this line:[self getObjects:arrayObjects range:NSMakeRange(0UL, arrayCount)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is almost the same as in the link [Sending "NSString *_strong*to parameter of type _unsafe_unretained id* "change retain/release properties of pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868603/sending-nsstring-strongto-parameter-of-type-unsafe-unretained-id-change-r) given by Ranju Patel above:

```
__unsafe_unretained id arrayObjects[arrayCount];
id objectKeys[arrayCount];
[self getObjects:arrayObjects range:NSMakeRange(0UL, arrayCount)];
```

because `getObject:range:` is declared as

```
- (void)getObjects:(id __unsafe_unretained [])objects range:(NSRange)range;
```

The reason is that ARC cannot manage the lifetime of objects in a plain C array,
therefore the objects have to be declared as `__unsafe_unretained`.
This is also explained in "Common Issues While Converting a Project"
in the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).